# Can't save php string to a custom field

Tags: php, functions, custom-field

I'm trying to find a way to save an mp3 link in `the_content` to a custom field (using ACF).

Posts in `the_content` look like this:

> http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/347813964-scott-johnson-27-tms-1361-pm.mp3
>
> Description of the audio file

I can extract the mp3 link in my theme using `preg_match_all` but it would be a lot better to save the mp3 link to a custom field than using PHP to extract.

```
<?php $pattern = "/(http|https):\/\/.*\/(.*)\.(mp3|m4a|ogg|wav|wma)/";
$subject = get_the_content();
preg_match_all ($pattern, $subject, $matches);
echo $matches[0][0];?>
```

The above will show only the mp3 link. The code below is what I'm using in my theme's `functions.php`. I have an ACF textbox called `audio_url` in the editor that doesn't save anything, just a blank box when I save a post.

```
function save_url_link($post_id){
$pattern = "/(http|https):\/\/.*\/(.*)\.(mp3|m4a|ogg|wav|wma)/";
$subject = get_the_content($post_id);
preg_match_all ($pattern, $subject, $matches);
update_post_meta($post_id, 'audio_url', $matches[0][0]);}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_url_link' );
```

Comment: `pdate_post_meta` is missing a `u`

Comment: Accidentally removed it during spacing, is in original

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, your `$subject` variable is empty when you call `get_the_content($post_id)`.

When using [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) hook, you can pass additional arguments like `$post` and `$update` to your callback.

For your case, you could use the second argument `$post` to grab the post contents.

**Code:**

```
function save_url_link( $post_id, $post ){
    $pattern = "/(http|https):\/\/.*\/(.*)\.(mp3|m4a|ogg|wav|wma)/";
    $subject = $post->post_content;
    preg_match_all ( $pattern, $subject, $matches );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'audio_url', $matches[0][0] );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_url_link', 10, 2 );
```

The above code uses the logic you implemented, with some differences.

1. Now we are using the second parameter `$post` in the callback, and we're picking up the submitted post content via `$post->post_content`.
2. [`add_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)'s fourth argument is the the number of arguments your callback will take. Default is `1`. We are using `2` because we now have `$post_id` and `$post`.